# What's wrong with this: \renewcommand{fnum@figure}{\textsc{Figure~\thefigure}}

Tags: macros, numbering

As the title suggests, I am not sure why my file will not compile. Here is a MWE:

```
  \documentclass{amsart}
  \renewcommand{fnum@figure}{\textsc{Figure ~\thefigure}}
  \begin{document}
         Dude!
  \end{document}
```

Here's an interesting part of the `.log` file:

```
 ! Missing control sequence inserted.
  <inserted text> 
            \inaccessible 
 l.2 \renewcommand{fnum@figure}
                          {\textsc{Figure ~\thefigure}}
 Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say `\def\cs{...}'.
 I've inserted an inaccessible control sequence so that your
 definition will be completed without mixing me up too badly.
 You can recover graciously from this error, if you're
 careful; see exercise 27.2 in The TeXbook.
```

Comment: The reason is that `@` has category code 12 ("other"); you need to make it of category code 11 ("letter"); `\makeatletter` simply changes the catcode of `@` to 11 (so now `@` behaves like a normal letter) and `\makeatother` changes the catcode of `@` to 12.

Comment: and the backslash \ is missing, i.e. `fnum@figure` vs `\fnum@figure`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Nice to know. I had to google to understand. Thanks for the input. `:-)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should read as

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\textsc{Figure ~\thefigure}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
     Dude!
\end{document}
```